# Performance improvement on vb.net code

Tags: vb.net, optimization, vb.net-2010

I need to write 50 million records with 72 columns into text file, the file size is growing as 9.7gb .

I need to check each and every column length need to format as according to the length as defined in XML file.

Reading records from oracle one by one and checking the format and writing into text file.

To write 5 crores records it is taking more than 24 hours. how to increase the performance in the below code.

```
Dim valString As String = Nothing
        Dim valName As String = Nothing
        Dim valLength As String = Nothing
        Dim valDataType As String = Nothing
        Dim validationsArray As ArrayList = GetValidations(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\ReportFormat.xml")
        Console.WriteLine("passed xml")
        Dim k As Integer = 1


        Try
            Console.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Now())
            Dim selectSql As String = "select * from table where
            " record_date >= To_Date('01-01-2014','DD-MM-YYYY') and record_date <= To_Date('31-12-2014','DD-MM-YYYY')"
            Dim dataTable As New DataTable
            Dim oracleAccess As New OracleConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("OracleConnection"))
            Dim cmd As New OracleCommand()
            cmd.Connection = oracleAccess
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.CommandText = selectSql
            oracleAccess.Open()
            Dim Tablecolumns As New DataTable()
            Using oracleAccess
                Using writer = New StreamWriter(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\FileName.txt")
                    Using odr As OracleDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                        Dim sbHeaderData As New StringBuilder
                        For i As Integer = 0 To odr.FieldCount - 1
                            sbHeaderData.Append(odr.GetName(i))
                            sbHeaderData.Append("|")
                        Next
                        writer.WriteLine(sbHeaderData)
                        While odr.Read()
                            Dim sbColumnData As New StringBuilder
                            Dim values(odr.FieldCount - 1) As Object
                            Dim fieldCount As Integer = odr.GetValues(values)
                            For i As Integer = 0 To fieldCount - 1
                                Dim vals As Array = validationsArray(i).ToString.ToUpper.Split("|")
                                valName = vals(0).trim
                                valDataType = vals(1).trim
                                valLength = vals(2).trim

                                Select Case valDataType
                                    Case "VARCHAR2"
                                        If values(i).ToString().Length = valLength Then
                                            sbColumnData.Append(values(i).ToString())
                                            'sbColumnData.Append("|")
                                        ElseIf values(i).ToString().Length > valLength Then
                                            sbColumnData.Append(values(i).ToString().Substring(0, valLength))
                                            'sbColumnData.Append("|")
                                        Else
                                            sbColumnData.Append(values(i).ToString().PadRight(valLength))
                                            'sbColumnData.Append("|")
                                        End If
                                    Case "NUMERIC"
                                        valLength = valLength.Substring(0, valLength.IndexOf(","))
                                        If values(i).ToString().Length = valLength Then
                                            sbColumnData.Append(values(i).ToString())
                                            'sbColumnData.Append("|")
                                        Else
                                            sbColumnData.Append(values(i).ToString().PadLeft(valLength, "0"c))
                                            'sbColumnData.Append("|")
                                        End If
                                        'sbColumnData.Append((values(i).ToString()))
                                End Select
                            Next
                            writer.WriteLine(sbColumnData)

                            k = k + 1
                            Console.WriteLine(k)
                        End While
                    End Using
                    writer.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Now())
                End Using
            End Using

            Console.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Now())
            'Dim Adpt As New OracleDataAdapter(selectSql, oracleAccess)
            'Adpt.Fill(dataTable)
            Return Tablecolumns
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Now())
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " & ex.Message)
            Console.ReadLine()
            Return Nothing
        End Try
```

Comment: i suggest Code review for you

Comment: Can you help me what needs to be done to slow down the time line in the process

Comment: The aforementioned comment is very clear. This is not a question suitable for SO (i.e., questions about specific problems), but for Code Review (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), where you can ask about more complex issues in a code, like performance analysis.